# Symfony2: Doctrine throws exception "Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object"

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I can't figure out why my association isn't working.

The error I'm getting is below:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object in http://localhost/Projects/clariture/app/src/Clariture/Models/Channel.php on line 32
```

My code is below:

```
<?php

namespace Clariture\Classes;

class Entity {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $dateCreated = 0;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $dateUpdated = 0;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set($name, $value) {

        $this->$name = $value;

    }

}

<?

namespace Clariture\Entities;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="Channels")
 */
class Channel extends \Clariture\Classes\Entity {

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=140)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $token;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ServiceLine", mappedBy="channels")
     */
    protected $serviceLine;

}

<?

namespace Clariture\Entities;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ServiceLines")
 */
class ServiceLine extends \Clariture\Classes\Entity {

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=140)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $active;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Channel", inversedBy="serviceLine")
     */
    protected $channels;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="serviceLines")
     **/
    protected $group;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->channels = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }

}

<?php

namespace Clariture\Controllers;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ChannelController extends \Clariture\Classes\Controller {

    public $roles = [_USER_ROLE_ADMIN];

    public function create($channelType) {

        $accessToken = $this->request->get('accessToken');
        $serviceLineId = $this->request->get('serviceLineId');
        $groupId = $this->request->get('groupId');

        $this->monolog->addDebug('accessToken: ' . $accessToken);
        $this->monolog->addDebug('serviceLineId: ' . $serviceLineId);

        $name = null;
        /* get the extended access token */
        switch($channelType) {

            default:
            case _CHANNEL_TYPE_FACEBOOK:
                $this->facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                $this->facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
                $accessToken = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
                $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
                $name = $user['name'];
            break;

        }

        $group = $this->em->find('Clariture\Entities\Group', $groupId);     
        $serviceLine = $this->em->find('Clariture\Entities\ServiceLine', $serviceLineId);

        $channel = new \Clariture\Entities\Channel;
        $channel->token = $accessToken;
        $channel->type = $channelType;
        $channel->name = $name;
        $channel->serviceLine = $serviceLine;

        $channel->group = $group;
        $channel->dateCreated = time();
        $serviceLine->channels->add($channel);
        $group->channels->add($channel);
        // $this->monolog->addDebug('serviceLine: ' . print_r($serviceLine, 1));

        $this->em->persist($channel);
        $this->em->flush();

    }

<?php

namespace Clariture\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="groups")
 */
class Group extends \Clariture\Classes\Entity {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", unique=true, length=140)
     */

    protected $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="parent")
     **/
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="children")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ServiceLine", inversedBy="group")
     **/
    protected $serviceLines;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Channel", inversedBy="group")
     **/
    protected $channels;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->channels = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }

}
```

Comment: The exception states an error in `Clariture\Models\Channel` on line 32 but you didn't add this class to your question. What are you trying to do? persist a new entity ? update an existing one? Please provide a little more information.

Comment: Sorry, added that class :)

Comment: freaky active record pattern btw. - are you sure you know what you're doing there? Anyways my answer should resolve your issue :)

Comment: Freaky? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Please don't get me wrong - i'm just trying to help :) The "Freaky" was targeting your code-style - no setters, strange object instanciation chain, mixing php 5.4 style `[]` and old `array()` syntax here and there... Looks pretty mixed together and active record patterns with doctrine are not that easy to implement.

Comment: add `\Clariture\Classes\Model` to the question please i can't see how your `get()` and `model()` methods look. Those are actually responsible for object creation.

Comment: I don't believe they are relevant, considering the models get loaded just fine. The issue appears to be related to the entity. I'm using magic __get() and __set() methods; the "strange" object instanciation chain is because I'm using Silex and I have to pass $app around everywhere, heh.

Comment: Also, not really using a true Active Record pattern here. All data will need to be explicitly saved to the DB using methods like create() and update() which will target the records that need to be updated explicitly using Doctrine Entities. The Model classes are just a wrapper to make it easier to interact with the Entity classes.

Comment: Edited the code - should hopefully be easier to read now :)

Answer (score 1):

The critical code should be:

```
$serviceLine->channels->add($channel);
$group->channels->add($channel);
```

`$serviceLine` or `$group` aren't correctly instanciated resulting in `$serviceLine->channels`or `$group->channels` not holding an instance of `Collection` at the point where you're trying to call `add(..)` on them.

Make sure you have ...

```
public function __construct 
{
    $this->channels = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

... inside your `ServiceLine` and `Group` classes and create the objects using the `new` syntax.

Comment: If you look, the ServiceLine entity actually has that bit in the constructor already. Also, the ServiceLine and Group objects that I'm trying to associate already exist in the database.

FYI, $serviceLine->get() returns the entity (line 14 of my Channel Model)

Comment: Which line exactly is line 32 where the exception comes from?

Comment: Line 32 is `$serviceLine->channels->add($channel);`